# Deploying Bokeh plot using EC2 and ngnix

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bokeh, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to deploy a Bokeh plot on an EC2. For this, I followed the documentation and used the command `bokeh serve myapp.py --address ec2-address-1.amazonaws.com:80`, but I get the following error: **ERROR -2**. I also used nginx, I have been able to display web test pages on the EC2, but when I try to display the Bokeh plot I get the same error: **ERROR -2**. On the EC2, I have the following internal rules
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBjIj.png).

To deploy the plot using nginx, I used the command:   `bokeh serve myapp.py --port 5100 --prefix=/Test/ --address ec2-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com:80`  and used configuration from the documentation:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ec2-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

    access_log  /tmp/bokeh.access.log;
    error_log   /tmp/bokeh.error.log debug;

    location /Test/ {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_buffering off;
 
    }
}
```

What does ERROR -2 mean? How can I deploy the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved  my problem. The error was that I had two configurations in nginx, and  I was not using by default the posted configuration. I moved the posted conf to `/etc/nginx/sites-available`  and renamed to  `default`, while also changing the original default name to `default.bak`. Then I only had to run `bokeh serve myapp.py --port 5100 --prefix=/Test/ --allow-websocket-origin=ec2-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and everthing worked.